# Blitz++: Filling an array with random numbers

Tags: c++, random, multidimensional-array, blitz++

I am trying to compare the performance of Blitz++ / Armadillo / Eigen and my own library.

I am currently doing the following using Blitz++:

```
...
Array<T, 1> s(samples);
Uniform<T> rand;
rand.seed((unsigned int)time(0));
for(size_t i=0; i<samples; i++) {
    s = rand.random() *4.0 +58.0;
}
...
```

To be fair I need to know the correct "Blitz++" way of filling an array with random numbers.
I assume that the above code-snippet is NOT the way to do it since is is massively inefficient.

**In short**

Is the above snippet the correct way of initializing an array with random numbers when using Blitz++ or is there are better / more efficient way?

Comment: Bear in mind that with these type of comparisons you can end up comparing apples to oranges. For example, there are several ways of [accessing elements](http://arma.sf.net/docs.html#element_access) in Armadillo: operator(), operator[], iterators, or memptr(). By default, operator() has bounds checking enabled, while the other ways do not. This helps in development. As such, for a more balanced comparison, you also need to take into account how long it actually takes to develop software using a particular library (including debugging!), and how readable/maintainable your final code is.

Comment: @mtall, I agree there are multiple aspects to take into consideration when comparing these types of libraries. It is however not all apples and pears... you just need to compare them fairly. Hence I am not comparing the element-wise access of one library with the with whole-array operations of another. But separating comparison on: whole-array operations, stencils/views, element-wise operations, initialization / generators.

Comment: Even then there's more to consider. For example, many C++ libraries can use various BLAS backends for whole-array operations. Does one compare standard BLAS, or a highly optimised version such as OpenBLAS or Intel MKL ?  Whole-array operations are also affected by whether the matrices are allocated dynamically, or are fixed-size (ie. size specified as template parameters). In the latter case, a C++ compiler may produce better code. This in turn brings in questions about a given compiler's abilities, eg. one compiler might optimise more/less than another for a given piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing my question, I realized the error of my ways.

The answer to the question is:

You are doing it wrong, do it like so:

```
...
Array<T, 1> s(samples);
Uniform<T> rand;
rand.seed((unsigned int)time(0));
s = rand.random() *4.0 +58.0;
...
```

So now the question is, is my own answer correct?